# Click on Javascript used for pagination using Selenium and Python.

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to selenium and currently using Python 2.7 for same. I want to click on some Javascripts which are being used for pagination in the website. I am adding the link to the page. Please help me out with hints or code? Thank you!

http://www.mouser.in/new/circuit-protection/n-5g3c

Comment: What have you tried so far? what do you want to create? And please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code to click on pagination 2

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.mouser.in/new/circuit-protection/n-5g3c")
hrefvalue=driver.find_element_by_id("2").get_attribute('href')
driver.execute_script(hrefvalue);
```